# Is there an easy way to convert MS Word Layouts into LaTeX Templates?

Tags: templates, msword

I am a computer science major, and love using LaTeX, because of its simplicity. My Fiance wants to use it to, but has different requirements, and cant just use the Lecture Notes in Computer Science (Lncs). 
Im trying really hard to wrap my head around the lncs.cls file, but cant get it to work. To illustrate i will append this with the requirements, maybe someone has a similar file laying around and is willing to share. Im NOT asking you to code it for me. I just didnt know how to ask without showing my starting point.
A script that converts Word Templates into Latex Templates would work perferctly too.
Thank you very much.

(PS: Requirements for Layouts:
Left an Right Border: 3.5 cm
Upper and Lower border: 2 cm

Font: Times New Roman
Size: 12pt
Line Spacing: 1.5 Lines
Spacing to next Text: 6pt
Form: Justified (im not a native english speaker, i mean when the text looks like a box)

Title 1: Spacing Upwards: 12pt
Fontsize: 14pt, bold
Spacing Downwards: 6pt

Title 1: Spacing Upwards: 12pt
Fontsize: 12pt, bold
Spacing Downwards: 0pt

Title 1: Spacing Upwards: 12pt
Fontsize: 12pt, bold
Spacing Downwards: 6pt

Footnotes: 
Fontsize 10
Line Spacing: 1 line
form: Justified (again...)
indent: inwards 1cm hanging indent

Pictures and tables:
Title (Above picture) 12pt, bold
Source (Underneath) 10pt
)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Sadly, I know of no conversion tool, but if one exists, I would really like to hear about it.  That said, there seems to be one small bit of information missing from these specs -- what is the textwidth or paper size?  I assume A4, but if it's something else, the result would not be what is wanted.

Comment: This is all pretty easy stuff with `geometry`, `titlesec` and `caption`.

Comment: `lncs.cls` is basically a (heavily) customized version of the standard LaTeX `article` class. It might be easier to customize `article` directly, rather than piling another set of modifications on top of what has already been done.

Comment: Where do these requirements come from? There are already classes for lots of styles (e.g., APA).